# File rename while uploading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I am uploading the files to Amazon s3 from my rails app and it is working fine, however, I want to know how I can append some string to the file which is to be uploaded. For example if the user has chosen the file abc.jpg, I need to append it as header_abc.jpg. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
path = picture.attachment.path()

new_file_name = "header_" + picture.attachment_file_name

FileUtils.move(path, File.join(File.dirname(path), new_file_name))

picture.attachment_file_name = new_file_name
picture.save
```

Comment: while uploading rails creates a temp file i need to change that name. Is there any possibility to be specified in the model itself ? when we are defining attachable

Answer (score 0):

Assume you're using paperclip from the tags list.

In our model:

`has_attached_file :image, :path => ":rails_root/public/images/header_:basename.:extension"`

Comment: I have an attachment model all my Models which has attachments will use it i need to specifically change it for one model alone

Answer (score 0):

```
has_attached_file :image,
                :styles => { :medium => ["140x140>", :jpg],
                             :thumb => ["109x82>", :jpg],
                             :small => ["54x41>", :jpg],
                             :article => ["500x500>", :jpg] },
                :storage => :s3,
                :s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/s3.yml",
                :path => "article/:id/:style.:extension",
                :bucket => S3_BUCKET
```

[paperclip wiki](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Interpolations)